# Stargazer output appears below text - rmarkdown to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, pandoc, stargazer

**The Problem**

When using rmarkdown in RStudio, my `stargazer(glm())` output gets positioned below the text that I would like it to. It gets positioned in a different spot than the `r chunk` is.

The PDF is created perfectly, it's just the position of the `stargazer` output that is a problem.

**Background**

I am trying to create a PDF with lots of text and a couple of `stargazer` `glm()` output between a few of the paragraphs. When I put more than one `stargazer()` output in my rmarkdown file and then "Knit" to PDF, the `stargazer()` output gets moved down below the text.

I would like the `stargazer output` to get positioned where I put the `r chunks`.

I do not have the same problem when using inserting `ggplot2()` output in a similar manner.

**Failed Attempts**

I have tried as many combinations as I know how of positioning my `r chunks` arguments. (Just in case)

I have tried every combination of tab vs. spaces, before and after paragraphs/headers/r-chunks/etc. (That was a problem I had once with ggplot2 output)

I have referenced the following StackOverflow Questions:

- [Using fig.pos = "H" and fig.pos = "h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696172/how-to-hold-figure-position-with-figure-caption-in-pdf-output-of-knitr?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [This very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626462/figure-position-in-markdown-when-converting-to-pdf-with-knitr-and-pandoc?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Yihui Xie's examples](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/)
- [Stargazer and RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670299/using-stargazer-with-rstudio-and-knitr/30423627)
- I tried using "\" at the end of (and between) chunks as mentioned in one of the above posts.

**Reproducible Example**

A reproducible example of my work problem:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, echo = FALSE}
library(stargazer)

mtcars_glm <- glm(formula = vs ~ disp + am + cyl + mpg, family = "binomial", data = mtcars)

```

# Heading1

I have tried creating paragraphs like this.

    I have also tried creating paragraphs with 2 indents.

## Heading2

Lets try to create a couple of nice tables with stargazer.

```{r attempt1, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}

stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), header = FALSE)

```

And then we will add some text down here, too.

```{r attempt2, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}

stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), header = FALSE)

```

And some more text.

```{r attempt3, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}

stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), header = FALSE)

```

Lets see what happens.

### Heading3

```{r plot_attempt}

boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl)
```

# Second Section

## Second Header
````

Here are the 3 pages of output:

Page #1
[image: Page 1]

Page #2
[image: Page 2]

Page #3
[image: Page 3]

Here is my sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stargazer_5.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.4     yaml_2.1.19     Rcpp_0.12.16    stringi_1.1.7   rmarkdown_1.9  
[11] knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.0   digest_0.6.15   evaluate_0.10.1
```

**Thanks**

If you can help me, thanks. I do not know much about LaTeX or Pandoc, so I imagine it is some sort of knowledge gap. Feel free just to point me in the right direction, too, if you think you've found a solution.

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `float = FALSE`, you will not have any of the features that come with a floating environment, such as captions (i.e. the title) or labels. Instead, consider setting an unconditional table placement with the `float` package. As an example, consider the following document (I use `\clearpage` to start the body on page 2 so we can see the adjoining pages on the screenshot):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{lipsum}
output: pdf_document
---
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
```{r setup, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
library(stargazer)
mtcars_glm <- glm(formula = vs ~ disp + am + cyl + mpg, family = "binomial", data = mtcars)
```

Table 1 here.
```{r tab1, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), 
          header = FALSE, title = "Table 1")
```

\lipsum[2-3]
Table 2 here.
```{r tab2, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), 
          header = FALSE, title = "Table 2")
```

\lipsum[4]
````

which gives
[image]

where Table 2 has been bumped to the following page, and the text after Table 2 has been moved up. This is how LaTeX behaves; it does not want to leave too much white space at the bottom of the page.  To insist that Table 2 follows a piece of text, you can use the `H` specifier (which requires the `float` LaTeX package). Here's the same document, but note the `table.placement` argument in the `tab2` chunk:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \usepackage{lipsum}
output: pdf_document
---
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
```{r setup, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
library(stargazer)
mtcars_glm <- glm(formula = vs ~ disp + am + cyl + mpg, family = "binomial", data = mtcars)
```

Table 1 here.
```{r tab1, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), 
          header = FALSE, title = "Table 1")
```

\lipsum[2-3]
Table 2 here.
```{r tab2, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), 
          header = FALSE, title = "Table 2", table.placement = "H")
```

\lipsum[4]
````

which gives
[image]

The table is placed after the text ("Table 2 here"), even at the expense of leaving white space at the bottom of the page. An alternative is `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19766/how-to-control-the-position-of-floating-images.

In general, you should leave float (i.e. tables and figures) placements to LaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat for an extensive discussion.

Comment: I saw that you posted this while I was typing the very similar solution I had found. [(See Other Post)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259550/9017311) Thank you for your help and all of the work you put into your response and for providing additional resources. It helps me understand more about where I went wrong and how to adjust course for next time.

Comment: Ah. I missed `table.placement`. I was thinking there might be a built-in option in stargazer somewhere without manually tweaking the resulting tex file. It is my first time to encounter the package myself and didn't read through the whole documentation since i was on mobile. +1

Answer (score 1):

Set `float = FALSE`. From the manual,

```
float: a logical value that indicates whether the resulting table will be a 
floating table (set off, for instance, by \begin{table} and \end{table}).
```

In LaTeX, a `table` environment is a floating environment.

E.g.

```
stargazer(mtcars_glm, ci=FALSE, no.space = TRUE, report = c("vc*"), float = FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you @hpesoj626. I never suspected the solution to lie within the function itself. I appreciate your help.