# Stargazer Title Not Showing (Non-reproducible Error)

Tags: r, pdf, stargazer

WARNING: I was not able to reproduce the error in a separate R/RStudio session, so I am hoping just to get some leads on trouble shooting my current `.rmd` script.

**The Problem**

All of a sudden, the stargazer title argument seemed to stop working. No matter what the title was or where I placed the argument within the function, it does not seem to work.

Additionally, and maybe related, I started getting this warning message:

`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

**Background**

After @hpesoj626 helped me answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50243929/9017311), the titles disappeared from my tables. Though not explicitly set in that example, `stargazer`'s / `LaTeX`'s default title was still being shown. After using the solution in that post, the titles disappeared.

I wanted to add a customized title to the tables by using the `title = ""` argument. This doesn't seem to help.

**Attempts**

- I have tried using other character vector arguments to see if they
  work, like `dep.var.labels = c()`, and everything seems to work just
  fine.
- I have tried reinstalling and updating the `stargazer` package.
- I have tried removing all other arguments besides `...` and `title = ""`
- I tried different chunk options. (`results='asis'`, `echo=FALSE`, etc.)
- I have tried to restart R / Rstudio every way I know how
- I have tried copying and pasting the .rmd file code to a completely separate script.
- I was not able to find similar problems on SO.

As you will see in the below section, I have other packages loaded via namespace since I am loading `.rda` objects into my session using `load()`. I am loading `glm()` objects and `ggplot()` objects into my R/Rstudio session. Even when doing this in the example session, I have not able to reproduce the error.

**Differences Between Linked Reproducible example and Actual Session**

The only differences I can see between my example data and my actual data is that the generated LaTeX code for my actual data is missing this:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{}
```

My actual data contains this:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And my actual sessionInfo() has a few more packages loaded via namespace:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stargazer_5.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16      digest_0.6.15     grid_3.4.4        plyr_1.8.4        gtable_0.2.0      scales_0.5.0.9000 ggplot2_2.2.1     pillar_1.2.1      rlang_0.2.0.9001 
[10] lazyeval_0.2.1    labeling_0.3      tools_3.4.4       munsell_0.4.3     yaml_2.1.19       compiler_3.4.4    colorspace_1.3-2  knitr_1.20        tibble_1.4.2
```

Do some of the packages loaded via namespace conflict with `stargazer`, `LaTeX`, or other packages?

**Thanks**

I know I wasn't able to provide the most information, given I wasn't able to reproduce the error myself, but I do appreciate any insight you might have on trouble shooting the problem. If you are able to provide some guidance, thank you.

Comment: See my answer to your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, I was able to figure out a solution.

I had not realized this, but including `float = FALSE` in the `stargazer()` function, removes this part of the generated LaTeX code:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{}
```

Which is where the title would go. But without using the `float = FALSE`, I wouldn't be able to position my tables where I wanted. And `table.placement = "htbp"` or any combination of those letters didn't position the tables properly and `table.placement = "H"` threw an error.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32334582/9017311), I was able to put the following code in my YAML header and use `table.placement = "H"` and keep float = `TRUE`:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Name"
output: pdf_document
fig.caption: yes
keep_tex: yes
header-includes: \usepackage{float}
---
```

Which places my tables in the appropriate place AND allows me to put titles on the tables.

Comment: Also see @Weihuang Wong 's answer on my first post. It goes into much more depth and has links to more resources.