# How to fit a stargazer table on a particular page/section in R-markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, stargazer

I used stargazer for some regression tables in my r markdown document. I would like some of the tables to appear on a particular page.

The code for my regressions/stargazer tables is located near text that I want them to appear next to. However, the tables display toward the bottom of the document.

Comment: Have you read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50243929/10215301) and tried some suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259504/10215301) already, first, you would have to include `table.placement = "H"` argument into `stargazer()` function. You may need to put `header-includes   - \usepackage{float}` in the YAML section, too.